# keyboard event handling

Tags: java

i m doing the project on remote screen capturing and controlling.... i have done the screen capturing.... now i watn to make controlling....in it i want....
i have done the controlling through mouse events like mouseMove & mousePressed,mouseReleased...
but the  ***controlling by Keyboard*** is not done...so tell me how to do KeyBoard events on robot class and using it how to make controlling...?

so suggest me the solution for how to make controlling by keyboard event....
thanks...

Comment: i think i have seen this question before. to be clear, you are wondering how to capture key events from a remote keyboard?  or are you wondering how to send key events to a client and have all of the listeners react accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Robot`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class has both [`keyPress`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress(int)) and [`keyRelease`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyRelease(int)) method which can be used to cause key events on a machine.

The following is a little demonstration code that I tried out that launches Notepad in Windows, waits half a second and types `hello` into it:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad");

Robot r = new Robot();
r.setAutoDelay(100);
r.delay(500);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
```

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks the interface to the Robot class looks really bad?

Comment: True, it doesn't look very elegant.

Comment: I concur - it needs improvement.